# Replace Pivot Table row names

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm attempting to create a spreadsheet to process attendance data. The data is in the form of lists of ID numbers of present members at each meeting.

```
9/21/13 | 9/22/13 | 9/23/13
123456  | 408437  | 123456
408437  | 349343  | 349343  
349343  | 408437  |
        | 739848  |
```

I also have a list with ID numbers and Member Names

```
ID Numbr| Name
123456  | John
408437  | Joe
349343  | Suzy
739848  | Bob
ETC...
```

I've created a pivot table to track meeting attendance

```
ID Numbr| 9/21/13 | 9/22/13 | 9/23/13 
123456  | 1       | 1       | 1
408437  | 0       | 0       | 1
349343  | 1       | 0       | 1
739848  | 1       | 1       | 0
ETC...
```

But I'd like the pivot table to display names of members instead of their ID numbers. This seems like a job for VLOOKUP but I can't find a way to implement it in the pivot table. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A small point: in your data (first listing) it looks like "Joe" attended the 9/22/13 meeting twice.  And in general, your pivot table isn't consistent with your first listing.

Comment: Yeah, the data here isn't accurate. I just wanted to show how I had my sheet formatted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `VLOOKUP` as a calculated field in a pivot table.

There are 2 options:

1. Add the `VLOOKUP` to an area next to the pivot table
2. Add the `VLOOKUP` as an extra column on your data

Answer (score 0):

+1 on doing the VLOOKUP in an extra column of your source data.
Doing it next to the PivotTable can become a problem if you your pivot table grows or otherwise needs to be moved later on.

Alternatively, you could manually replace the IDs with their respective names in the PivotTable and it should be kept in memory upon refreshing the data (at least in Office 2013/2016) but I'd still recommend adding the names to the source data as a better solution.